# Return pointer on array of structs in ctype

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a c++ code that looks like this and I want to call it from python using ctypes:

c++ :

```
extern "C" Array<DetectionWindow>* getdets(const uint8_t *indatav, int rows, int cols){

/** Detection window struct */
typedef struct DetectionWindow
{
    ushort x;         /**< Top-left x coordinate */
    ushort y;         /**< Top-left y coordinate */
    ushort width;     /**< Width of the detection window */
    ushort height;    /**< Height of the detection window */
    ushort idx_class; /**< Index of the class */
    float  score;     /**< Confidence value for the detection window */
} DetectionWindow;

...
...

using DetectionWindowArray = Array<DetectionWindow>;

...

DetectionWindowArray win(100000);

Array<DetectionWindow>* dets = &win;

return dets ;
}
```

I don't think that actually really matters what I do in c++. What matters is that I am returning a pointer to an array of structs. Compiling the source code I managed to create the shared library that I want to use in python.

Python :

```
import numpy.ctypeslib as ctl
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import cv2
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

class detection(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [
                ('x', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('y', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('width', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('height', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('idx_class', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('score', ctypes.c_float)
             ]

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./lib/libmain.so")
getdets = lib.getdets

getdets.argtypes = [ctl.ndpointer(ctypes.c_uint8, flags='aligned, c_contiguous'), ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

img = cv2.imread('./data/image_0.jpg',0)

(???) = getdets(img , img.shape[0], img.shape[1])
```

How can I return and print all struct parameters for each element of the array through the pointer that I am returning in c++?

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable from `getdets`.  That won't work even if you figure out how to marshal an `Array<DetectionWindow>` into python.

Comment: I defined the variable as static DetectionWindowArray win(100000); I suppose that now I can access the same piece of memory between calls ....